# how to judge there is content in QTextEdit in QT?

Tags: qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have written a notepad which looks like notepad  in Windows. How to  set to make the  find action disabled when the QTextEdit empty but  enabled when  something in it

Answer (score 5):

The `myTextEdit->plainText().isEmpty()` procedure does not seem to be very efficient: The `plainText` method needs to convert the full QTextEdit contents into a new QString buffer, which is expensive if the QTextEdit contains a large amount of text.

I suggest to use `myTextEdit->document()->isEmpty()` instead, which queries the QTextDocument storage, i.e. the original data structure.

In my use case, the QTextEdit contains an error log, and before appending a line I check if the text is empty; if not, I insert a newline(*). Converting the log buffer to a QString each time a line is appended would be a bad idea.

(*) I cannot insert a newline together with each log entry, because the entries themselves are comma-separated lists. Roughly speaking I have a `newEntry(...)` and a `newLine(...)` function, and `newEntry` does not know if `newLine` or `newEntry` will be called next.

Comment: See [my answer to question 14550146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550146/qtextedit-scroll-down-automatically-only-if-the-scrollbar-is-at-the-bottom/57975092#57975092) for the full use case.

Answer (score 0):

You connect a function that enables/disables the action based on the text edits `plainText()`, to the `textChanged()` signal of the text edit.

For example:

```
void MyWidget::someSetupMethod()
{
    // ... some code that sets up myTextEdit and myFindAction here
    connect(myTextEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, myFindAction, [myTextEdit, myFindAction]() {
        myFindAction->setEnabled(!myTextEdit->plainText().isEmpty());
    });
    // ...
}
```

or, if you cannot or do not want to use C++11, something like

```
void MyWidget::someSetupMethod()
{
    // ... some code that sets up m_myTextEdit and m_myFindAction here
    connect(m_myTextEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this, &MyWidget::updateFindAction);
    // ...
}

void MyWidget::updateFindAction()
{
    m_myFindAction->setEnabled(!m_myTextEdit->plainText().isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: I written a  program like notepad in Windows. I use  code  to  make the  mainwindow.  Design the findDialog use  ui. But  i don't know how to use ui in class mainwindow. Such as  the ui  have  a  lineedit.how  to  use the lineedit  in  class  mainwindow?

Comment: In your mainwindow class' constructor you'll find something like `ui->setupUi(this)`. After that you can access the widgets from the `.ui` file through the `ui` object, for example `ui->textEdit`. Maybe you should follow [some widget examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets.html).

Comment: ，not really.but in fact. Ui->setui (This ) only in finddlg.h  ican use ui->okbutton in constructor of finddlg. When  i  add  #include "finddlg.h" in mainwindow.h i cannot use ui->button

Comment: ，not really.but in fact. Ui->setui (This ) only in finddlg.h  ican use ui->okbutton in constructor of finddlg. When  i  add  #include "finddlg.h" in mainwindow.h i cannot use ui->button